# Are there any design patterns that could work in this scenario?

Tags: java, design-patterns, rest

We have a system (Java web application) that's been in active development / maintenance for a long time now (something like ten years).

What we're looking at doing is implementing a RESTful API to the web app. This web application, using Jersey, will be a separate project with the intent that it should be able to run alongside the main application or deployed in the cloud.

Because of the nature and age of our application, we've had to implement a (somewhat) comprehensive caching layer on top of the database (postgres) to help keep load down. Anyway, for the RESTful API, the idea is that GET requests will go to the cache first instead of the database to keep load of the database.

The cache will be populated in a way to help ensure that most things registered API users will need should be in there.

If there is a cache miss, the needed data should be retrieved from the database (also being entered into the cache in the process).

Obviously, this should remain transparent from the RESTful endpoint methods in my code. We've come up with the idea of creating a 'Broker' to handle communications with the DB and the cache. The REST layer will simply pass across ids (if looking to retrieve) or populated Java objects (if looking to insert / update) and the broker will take care of retrieving / updating / invalidating, etc.

There is also the issue of extensibility. To begin with, the API will be living alongside the rest of servers so access to the database won't be an issue however if we deploy to the cloud, we're going to need a different Broker implementation that will communicate with the system (namely the database) in a different manner (potentially through the use of an internal API).

I already have a rough idea on how I can implement this but it struck me that is probably a problem for which a suitable pattern could exist. If I could follow an established pattern as opposed to coming up with my own solution, that'll probably be a better choice. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a normal service/DAO/etc. pattern to me, but I'm not really sure what kind of answer you're looking for. Normally the caching would be handled between the DAO and DB layers and the services are ignorant of caching concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache has an implementation of just such a cache that it calls a [SelfPopulatingCache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/constructs).

Requests are made to the cache, not to the database. Then if there is a cache miss Ehcache will call the database (or whatever external data source you have) on your behalf.

You just need to implement a [CacheEntryFactory](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/blocking/CacheEntryFactory.html) which has a single method:

```
Object createEntry(Object key) throws Exception;
```

So as the name suggests, Ehcache implements this concept with a pretty standard factory pattern...

Answer (score 0):

There's no pattern.  Just hide the initial DB services behind interfaces, build tests around their intended behavior, then switch in an implementation that uses the caching layer.  I guess dependency injection would be the best thing to help you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like decorator pattern will suit your need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern.

You can create an `DAO` interface for data access, something like:

```
Value get(long id);
```

And firstly create a direct DB implementation, then create a Cache implementation which calls underlying  `DAO` instance, in this case it should be the DB implementation.

The Cache implementation will try to get value from its own managed Cache, and from underlaying `DAO` if it fails.

So both of your old application or the REST will only see `DAO` interface, without knowing any implemntation details,  and in future you can change the implementation freely.

Answer (score 0):

The best design pattern for transparently caching HTTP requests is to use [an](http://trafficserver.apache.org/) [HTTP](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) [cache](http://www.squid-cache.org/).